# Read a file name and create a column with it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a filename called shoes_2016, how do I create a dataframe column called year and extract out the year according to the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract year with `split`, convert to integer and assign to DataFrame:

```
filename = 'shoes_2016.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df['year'] = int(filename.split('.')[0].split('_')[1])

print (df)
```

Or:

```
filename = 'shoes_2016.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filename).assign(year = int(filename.split('.')[0].split('_')[1]))
print (df)
```

EDIT:

```
import os

filename = 'c:/users/a/desktop/items/shoes_2016.xlsx'
y = int(os.path.basename(filename).split('.')[0].split('_')[1])
print (y)
2016
```

Or:

```
y = int(filename.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0].split('_')[1])
print (y)
2016

df = pd.read_csv(filename).assign(year = y)
```

Comment: Why did you remove mask and why is it needed?

Comment: @PrathikKini - Because I first think OP need filtering, then read question again and OP need new column

Comment: How do I split if my filename is 'c:/users/a/desktop/items/shoes_2016.xlsx'

Comment: @3xtimpacts - Answer is edited.