# Add new column year and extract given file name (pandas , glob, os)

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system, glob

I will like to read multiple file but when I added a new column year, error message given: list object has no attribute 'Split'. I want to be the same this. Reference: [I would like to have the same as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58298838/read-a-file-name-and-create-a-column-with-it)

File Name:
Shirt_2016,
Shirt_2017,
Shoe_2018,
Shoe_2019,

All file names are standardized with this format, item_year.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas
import numpy

path='/Item/'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.xlsx'))
data = []
for filename in files:
   df = pd.read_excel(filename,header=None)
   data.append(df)
df=pd.concat(data)

df['Year']= os.path.basename(files.split('.')[0],split['_'][1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

As the `AttributeError` suggests, the variable `files` that you're calling `split()` on is a list, not a string.

Instead, try setting the year on each dataframe when you instantiate it:

```py
for filename in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None)
    # Extract the year from the filename & save it
    # on your dataframe before you concatenate the data.
    year = filename.split('.')[0],split['_'][1]
    df['Year'] = year
    data.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Carolyn solution will work, but here is an alternative using pandas function str.extract: `df['year']=df['file'].str.extract('_(\d{4})',expand=True)`

Here is the rest of the code to show how it works:

```
files = [f"/Item/{f}.xlsx" for f in "Shirt_2016, Shirt_2017, Shoe_2018, Shoe_2019".split(', ')]
df = pd.DataFrame(files,columns=['file']) 

df['year']=df['file'].str.extract('_(\d{4})',expand=True)
df
```

[image]

By the way, when reading multiple files it is faster to create a list and then concat.

`df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f).assign(file=f) for f in files])`

The assign is wasteful, but reads clean. Even faster is to wrap this read into a function and then call parallel read: `joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(joblib.delayed(read)(f) for f in files)`.

where `def read(f): df = pd.read_excel(f); df['file']=f; return df`